# Alternative set theories

Tags: soft-question, set-theory, education, alternative-set-theories

This is a (soft!) question for students of set theory and their teachers.

OK: ZFC is the canonical set theory we all know and love. *But what other, alternative set theories, should a serious student encounter (at least to the extent of knowing that the theory exists, and about why it is thought interesting)?*

Suggestions might be **SP** (Scott-Potter), **NBG**, **NF**, **ZFA**, **IST**, **ETCS** (for a few sentences of explanation, see http://www.logicmatters.net/2013/03/tyl-14-alternative-set-theories/

But what would be on your list of alternative set theories would be it good for advanced students to hear about, if only briefly?

Comment: A student of set theory, or of mathematics in general?

Comment: There are also variants of ZF (with or without axiom of choice, or continuum hypothesis, or others). For french readers, [this](http://www.math.u-psud.fr/~guenard/Livres/Complements.pdf) is an excellent book on the subject.

Comment: @ChrisEagle Good question: I guess I was thinking about someone specializing in broadly "mathematical logic"-related stuff.

Comment: People interested in category theory, algebraic geometry should know about Grothendieck universes, and inaccessible cardinals.

Comment: Perhaps structural set theories like ETCS, I think I would have been happy if I'd seen it in course for a week or two. Although being structural, I think it requires an inherently different thinking than material set theory (e.g. ZFC) and the outcome might not be pleasant. Either way it seems to be worth a mentioning.

Comment: Oh I just see that you did mention ETCS in the list. In this case I withdraw my previous comment. Instead, however, I think that perhaps limiting the usual ZF schemata could be interesting (e.g. "constructive set theory" is often interested in bounded replacement or bounded comprehension schemata, which only include the axioms for bounded formulas).

Comment: Could you not use acronyms for each of them, that is, write them in full so we can know the names?

Comment: @PeterTamaroff Apart from **SP** these are quite well-known labels. But I did also give gave a link to explanations for those who were unsure ...

Comment: I don't love ZFC.

Comment: +1 Qiaochu, neither do I. And most people don't know it, they only know the three letters Z, F and C.

Comment: Many know at least naive set theory (see Halmos' book for an idea of what it's about), and it's enough for most purposes.

Comment: @PeterSmith , I wonder if you check your blog comments in the last days ? I have made two different comments , here , http://www.logicmatters.net/students/tyl/comment-page-1/#comment-42809 , but it seems that it doesn't appear for you .

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Peter, there are a couple of good survey papers on precisely this topic. Neither is quite exhaustive, but they provide good overviews (naturally, there is some overlap), and the second in particular also has an extensive bibliography:

> [MR2732673 (2012c:03152)](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2732673). Apostoli, Peter; Hinnion, Roland; Kanda, Akira; Libert, Thierry. *[Alternative set theories](https://doi.org/10.1016/B978-0-444-51555-1.50015-8)*. In **Handbook of the Philosophy of Science**, vol. 4., “Philosophy of mathematics”, Andrew D. Irvine, ed., 461–491, Elsevier/North-Holland, Amsterdam, 2009,

and

> [MR3409865](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=3409865). Holmes, M. Randall; Forster, Thomas; Libert, Thierry. *Alternative set theories*. In **Handbook of the History of Logic**, vol. 6, “Sets and Extensions in the Twentieth Century”, Dov Gabbay, Akihiro Kanamori, and John Woods, eds., 559–632, Elsevier/North-Holland, Amsterdam, 2012.

I am more familiar with the second one, so let me say a few words about its contents:

The paper begins by discussing (Section 2) Simple Type Theory, Mac Lane's and Zermelo's, not because they are alternative theories, but because they are needed to understand some of them (such as New Foundations and its variants), though the authors mention that "Zermelo set theory or variants of Zermelo set theory have been pressed into service themselves as alternative set theories, presumably by workers nervous about the high consistency strength of $\mathsf{ZFC}$."

Section 3 covers theories with classes: First Von Neumann-Gödel-Bernays and Kelley-Morse set theory, then Ackermann set theory (where non-set classes can belong to other classes, this theory is equiconsistent with $\mathsf{ZF}$), and then a weak system that they call  "Pocket set theory", an expansion due to Holmes of a suggestion by Rudy Rucker.

Section 4 covers theories with atoms and with anti-foundation axioms. They first discuss $\mathsf{ZFA}$, then Aczel's anti-foundation axiom, and Boffa's axiom (in this system, there is a proper class of $x$ with $x=\{x\}$, while in Aczel's system there is only one).

They continue in section 5 with New Foundations and related systems (such as the much better understood $\mathsf{NFU}$, where urelements are allowed). Naturally, this section occupies the main bulk of the paper.

Section 6 discussed Positive set theory and its fragments and variants, typically denoted $\mathsf{PST}$, perhaps with sub- and superscripts (an exception to this notation is the theory $\mathsf{GPK}^+_\infty$, mutually interpretable with an extension of Kelley-Morse by large cardinals). This leads to Topological set theory.

Since the systems in section 6 allow talk of super- or hyperuniveses, section 7 discusses systems motivated by non-standard analysis, such as Nelson's Internal set theory, or Vopěnka's.

Section 8 concludes the list and covers "curiosities": The double extension set theory of Andrzej Kisielewicz (that "has the property which is usually ascribed to New Foundations (we believe not entirely fairly) of being motivated by a syntactical trick without any semantic motivation"), and Zermelo's set theory extended by an axiom asserting that there is an elementary $j:V\to V$, which turns out to be significantly high in terms of consistency strength.

Let me add that the theory $\mathsf{ZF}$ augmented by such an axiom has also been studied, even fairly recently, but I would not classify it by any means as "alternative". In general, extensions of $\mathsf{ZF}$ via large cardinals, forcing, or inner-model theoretic considerations are just part of the standard set-theoretic landscape.

Something that the paper definitely does not cover is systems motivated by algebraic geometry, topos-theoretic, or categorical considerations, such as Grothendieck universes. On the topic of categorical set theory, and Lawvere’s Elementary Theory of the Category of Sets, there is a recent paper that has gathered some attention,

> [MR3193723](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=3193723). Leinster, Tom. *[Rethinking set theory](https://doi.org/10.4169/amer.math.monthly.121.05.403)*. Amer. Math. Monthly **121** (2014), no. 5, 403–415. Also available at [ArXiv:1212.6543](http://arxiv.org/abs/1212.6543).

(The original version of the entry on [Alternative axiomatic set theories](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/settheory-alternative/) at the [Stanford encyclopedia of philosophy](https://plato.stanford.edu/index.html), by Holmes, seems to have been used as a basis for the Holmes-Forster-Libert Handbook chapter. It has since been significantly revised.)

Finally, there is also Bourbaki's set theory, about which Adrian Mathias has written a few critiques. You may enjoy the [discussion](http://nforum.mathforge.org/discussion/1270/bourbaki-set-theory/) at the nForum.

Comment: There is an [article](http://math.boisestate.edu/~holmes/holmes/separticle.pdf) on Randall Holmes's webpage with the same title.

Comment: Yes, it appeared as "Alternative Axiomatic Set Theories" in the Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy, http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/settheory-alternative/, and clearly served as basis for the paper I mentioned.

Comment: Many thanks @AndresCaicedo! I knew the short version by Randall Holmes for SEP, but didn't know of this very helpful longer version.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo In the last paragraph, did you perhaps mean "Mathias" instead of "Mac Lane"?

Comment: Yes, thank you. Edited now.

Comment: One of the longer discussions on Leinster's paper is [in the n-Category Cafe](http://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2012/12/rethinking_set_theory.html), and in the trackbacks you can find a couple more links where discussions took place.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo And yes, I knew Tom Leinster's piece (and some of the interesting discussion of it, Asaf!): intriguing stuff indeed.

Answer (score 8):

There is the structural set theory [SEAR](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/SEAR) (and variants) by Mike Shulman.

SEAR takes as basic the notion of *sets*, *elements* and *relations*, and has as logical grounding dependent type theory, in that elements are typed by the set they belong to (unlike ZFC, elements are not themselves sets, and cannot belong to more than one set), and relations are typed by their domain and codomain. The axioms let you construct a category of sets with nice properties very quickly (i.e. a topos) and in the end you get something equiconsistent with ZF. There is an extension SEAR-C including the axiom of choice; this is equiconsistent with ZFC.

If anyone is counting, SEAR-C has 7 axioms, two of which are schema. If I was pressed, at the moment I'd nominate SEAR(-C) for my favourite foundational system.

(Aside: People should definitely learn the not-quite formalised contrast between *material* and *structural* set theories: the former is basically anything that treats elements as supreme, having independent existence and all there is, the latter is more isomorphism invariant and elements don't have independent existence (this is my own spin on it - there is no watertight definition). Note that 'categorical' set theory is subsumed by structural set theory, as SEAR is *not* given by axiomatising a category of sets, it just heads that way as it was invented and developed by category theorists)

Comment: How did I not make a joke on the fact that working with SEAR is searing? :-)

Comment: The page you link to is very imprecise; I cannot figure out what exactly are the axiom schemas. For instance axiom 1 uses the term "property" without at all defining it, but it is certainly not first-order unlike as stated. I presume quantifying over elements of a set is permitted, but what about quantifying over all sets or all relations? And is testing equality between elements of different sets permitted? Also, I cannot see how one can motivate axiom 5 (collection) by appealing to consequences of some inconsistent sentence, so is there any real justification? Thanks!

Comment: @user21820 I did not write that nLab page, so you might get better answers to your questions if you either ask a new question here or over on the nForum. The first is a better option because of more visibility and the fact you already have an account here. Mike Shulman, the creator of SEAR, frequents MO.

Comment: @DavidRoberts: Okay. I was thinking of asking a question, but I thought you might know the details since you wrote about it. Should I ask here or on MO?

Comment: MO, I think. I wasn't paying attention, and forgot this was M.SE :-/

Comment: Alright thanks! =)

Comment: @user21820 if you do ask on MO, please drop a link here, to assist in cross-linking the information for people to follow later on.

Comment: Reading the nForum, it looks like it can be formulated in FOLDS ?

Answer (score 4):

Kripke-Platek set theory is a well-explored axiomatisation of a weakened first-order set theory that gives it pleasing correlations with the language of second-order arithmetic (itself a first-order theory).

This is probably the most useful field of non-standard set theory to know if you are interested in second-order comprehension axioms, recursive model theory, or reverse mathematics.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest that some constructive alternatives to **ZF** should be on the list.

Martin-Löf Type Theory is not a set theory as such, but I think could still be included.

**IZF** and **CZF** are subtheories of **ZF** with intuitionistic logic instead of classical (no excluded middle). They can both expand to **ZF** when excluded middle is added as an axiom, and yet can also be extended with several non-classical axioms including:

- All functions $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ are continuous.
- Church's Thesis: all functions $\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ are computable
- Uniformity principle: for every formula $\phi$,  $(\forall x)(\exists n \in \omega)\phi(x, n) \rightarrow (\exists n \in \omega)(\forall x)\phi(x, n)$

Answer (score 2):

I presented in my web site [an expression of set theory](http://settheory.net) that seems new. My purpose in designing it, was to give a clean and efficient way to build mathematics from scratch for the interest of clever undergraduate students, providing a direct path to higher mathematical tools and meta-mathematical considerations.
This is not only a different formalization of set theory but a way to introduce mathematics combining this set theory with model theory.
To sum up the main differences of this set theory from ZF:

The basic kinds of objects are elements, sets and functions. Each element is either a set or a function or none (pure). More kinds of objects can either be seen as additional kinds or constructed from the previous ones : operations, relations, tuples.
Many symbols are admitted beyond the mere ∈ of ZF, most of which are not new but an official recognition of widely used mathematical notations, here taken as (more or less) primary. Some are in neither of both standard kinds of structure symbols of first-order logic (operators and predicates) but are a different kind of symbols: the binders, that bind a variable on a set. Apart from including bounded quantifiers as particular cases, examples include the function definer (E∋x↦…); the set-builders {x∈E|…} and {f(x)|x∈E}; symbols of union and product of a family of sets defined by a term. Also I express and justify a principle giving several axioms of set existence as particular cases.
Classes are defined not as objects of this set theory but as meta-objects.